# var result = await someFunc() returns an object but I expected list of object

Tags: javascript, async-await, indexeddb

I wrote following function for loading indexeddb. (from [IndexedDB 備忘メモ](https://qiita.com/41semicolon/items/c0bbace5eafc422f988a))
I think this function should return Array of object. But, sometimes it returns an object. What are the possibilities of bug ?
Chrome developer tool said type of object was Array during in "load" function. But, after received "records" is type of object.

```
    async function load(dbobj, db, index, range) {
      return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const saves = [];
        const req = db.transaction(dbobj.storeName).objectStore(dbobj.storeName).index(index).openCursor(range);
        const onfinished = () => {
          console.log(`${saves.length} saves found.`);
          if (saves.length > 0) {
            resolve(saves[saves.length - 1]);
          }
        };
        req.onerror = reject;
        req.onsuccess = (ev) => {
          const cur = ev.target.result;
          if (cur) {
            saves.push(cur.value);
            cur.continue();
          } else {
            onfinished();
          }
        };
      });
    }

    // example of receiving data
    var records = await load(dbobj, db, index, range);
```

Comment: `resolve(saves[saves.length - 1])` - if you want the whole array, that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are resolving only the value at the last index! resolve(saves) if you need the entire array;

```
async function load(dbobj, db, index, range) {
      return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const saves = [];
        const req = db.transaction(dbobj.storeName).objectStore(dbobj.storeName).index(index).openCursor(range);
        const onfinished = () => {
          console.log(`${saves.length} saves found.`);
          if (saves.length > 0) {
            resolve(saves); // you are resolving only the value at the last index! resolve(saves) if you need the entire array;
          }
        };
        req.onerror = reject;
        req.onsuccess = (ev) => {
          const cur = ev.target.result;
          if (cur) {
            saves.push(cur.value);
            cur.continue();
          } else {
            onfinished();
          }
        };
      });
    }
```